# Excel VBA Summarize large data set by User ID and Category

Tags: sql, excel, vba, summary

I'm trying to find a way to summarize a large data set (15,000 rows / 50 columns.  The 50 columns are ID, Category (5 unique categories) and a monthly total for 4 years.

Each ID could have the same category multiple times (because the monthly totals are from 3 different data sources.

What I need to end up with is each id can have a maximum of 5 rows. Some will have 2 or 3 or 4.  Not each ID will have 5.

I'm thinking of finding the start and end row for each id for each category.  Then summing each of the 50 columns 1 by 1, writing the total on the start line and delete the remaining rows for each category.

Repeat for the next ID / category combination.

Following is a below and after sample of what I'm trying to get to.  I guess I could do a pivot table and then read through the pivot table (before writing the data) but I'm not sure that is going to be much faster.  I've am very new to using SQL on an Excel data set and have only done a select based on specific criteria.  I have tried to use SQL and summarize the data but I'm not having much luck (because I don't know what I'm doing).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.....

[image]

Comment: You can do that easily enough in Power Query (available in Windows Excel 2010+and Office365).

Comment: @RonRosenfeld..........I'm adding this to a macro.  When I ran it a second time, it said the query already existed.  So, after a little research. I found a little code to refresh the query which I think will work.  My concern is I expect the number of rows to change each time the macro is run.  One time it might be 16,000 rows and then 12,000 rows.  I don't expect it to be the same each time.  When it ran the first time.  I set the range for the exact number of rows. Next time it will be different.  How do I address that.  Do I delete the query when I'm done.  Then add it next time?  Thanks

Comment: The query accesses the data by using the table name reference. A Table will automatically resize when you add/delete rows. So long as you don't bypass that with your code, shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld.....Thanks for the help....I appreciate your advice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table35"]}[Content],

//Set Data Types
//First two columns are Text and others set to Currency
    colTypes = {{"ID", Text.Type},{"Category", Text.Type}} & 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),2), each {_, Currency.Type}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,colTypes),

//Unpivot the "date" columns to get them into a single column    
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),

//Group by ID, Category and Attribute(=>Date)
//If there is more than one entry for a subgroup, SUM the values
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"ID", "Category", "Attribute"}, {
        {"Sum", each List.Sum([Value]), Currency.Type}}),

//Pivot on Dates (Attribute column) with no aggregation
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Sum")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]

Comment: @RonRosenfeld................Thanks...........I haven't used Power Query before.  I tried it and am getting an error after I copy M Code into the Advanced Editor.  It says "The column 'Category' of the table wasn't found.  Thanks for the info....

Comment: @Shaves `M` is case sensitive. So you may need to change the code from `Category` to `CATEGORY`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld..................thanks.  I'll check that out today.  Appreciate the help.........

Comment: @RonRosenfeld....................That did it.............This is great and will really speed up the process.  Thanks for your help...........

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [**`SUMIFS`**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) after de-duplicating the grouping columns:

1. Copy all content of grouping columns, `ID` and `Category`, and paste to desired region (i.e., new sheet).
2. De-duplicate the two grouping columns by using Ribbon option: Data > Remove Duplicates.

   [image: Excel Ribbon Icon for Remove Duplicates]
3. Add `SUMIFS` formulas adjacent to de-duplicate list pointing to original sheet. To propagate across all columns, drag formula down the first numeric column for all 15,000 rows and then across for all 50 columns. Be sure to lock the criteria ranges with `$`:

   ```
   =SUMIFS(OriginalSheet!C2:C15000, OriginalSheet!$A$2:$A$15000, $A2, OriginalSheet!$B$2:$B$15000, $B2)
   =SUMIFS(OriginalSheet!D2:D15000, OriginalSheet!$A$2:$A$15000, $A2, OriginalSheet!$B$2:$B$15000, $B2)
   =SUMIFS(OriginalSheet!E2:E15000, OriginalSheet!$A$2:$A$15000, $A2, OriginalSheet!$B$2:$B$15000, $B2)
   ...
   ```

---

Alternatively, for another non-VBA solution consider opening any MS Access database and directly query the workbook from a Query SQL window with an aggregate query.

[image: MS Access SQL Window]

Do note the square brackets (`[...]`) required due to your special Excel dated columns which start with numbers and contain special characters. You may need Excel and notepad to build below statement with all 50 columns

```sql
SELECT [ID]
      , [Category]
      , SUM([01/01/2018]) AS SumOf01012018
      , SUM([02/01/2018]) AS SumOf02012018
      , SUM([01/01/2019]) AS SumOf01012019
      ...

FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;Database=C:\Path\To\My\Excel\File.xlsx].[OriginalSheet$A1:AX15000]
GROUP BY [ID]
       , [Category]
```

Comment: @Parfait...........Thanks for the quick response.  I'm going to try these options and see what works best.  Thanks again for your help......